# LOAD DATA INFILE query never completes (yet data is loaded), mysqlimport rejects

Tags: mysql, innodb

Using different mysql clients, my `LOAD DATA INFILE` query never completes, but I can see the data has been successfully loaded. Where can I look to see why the driver gets stuck?

My complete command:

`mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql/staging_2.csv' INTO TABLE log_line FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (df_log_id,log_line_type,log_line_data,time_us,log_line_datetime);`

Alternatively I can use `mysqlimport` but can't get by the error `mysqlimport: Error: 2068, LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.` despite having local_infile on:

[image]

Command:

```
root@hei13-nix02:~/development/logs# mysqlimport --local
--fields-terminated-by='|' --lines-terminated-by='\n' --user=root --columns='df_log_id,log_line_type,log_line_data,time_us,log_line_datetime' dev_wingops log_line /var/lib/mysql/staging_2.csv
```

Error:

```
mysqlimport: Error: 2068, LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access., when using table: log_line
```

Note: I've setup the same environment on Windows, and I can load no problem with the query completing normally. it seems to only affect my linux instance.

Comment: What are the permissions on the file?

Comment: "never completes" -- You are saying that the "mysql>" prompt does not come back?  What if you type `SHOW WARNINGS;` and return?

Comment: @RickJames -rw-rw-rw- but like I said, it does load, I just never get the prompt back. No rows returned on ```SHOW WARNINGS;```